# How to right align some elements of WPF ListItem?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF listbox and have updated the list item data template to have essentially a 3 column layout.

I would like:

|status color|name|        buttons|

These are probably CSS terms but I want to float the status color and name to the left, which I've done, then I would like the buttons to be floated to the right, and always stay to the right even as the window gets wider.

I feel like I'm so close, the list item widths grow when the window gets wider, all I feel I have to do is tell the buttons to float right but can't figure out how. I've tried stack panels, a grid with a auto|*|auto column layout (With a stretch on the last column) and I've tried a dockpanel.

Here's my XAML:

```
    <Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Appsecute.Views.MainView2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:AppsecuteControls="clr-namespace:Appsecute.Controls"
        Title="APPSECUTE" Height="630" Width="480" Icon="/Appsecute;component/Images/icon.png" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro.Resources;component/Icons.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="0,0,12,0">
        <AppsecuteControls:NotifyIcon
            x:Name="NotifyIcon"
            Text="Appsecute"
            Icon="/Images/icon.ico" MouseDoubleClick="NotifyIconMouseDoubleClick" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <AppsecuteControls:NotifyIcon.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu StaysOpen="False">
                </ContextMenu>
            </AppsecuteControls:NotifyIcon.ContextMenu>
        </AppsecuteControls:NotifyIcon>

        <Grid Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Margin="12,0,0,24">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Content="APPLICATIONS" Height="auto" Name="LabelApplications" Grid.Row="0" Padding="2" Margin="0,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ListBox Height="auto" Name="ListBoxApplications" Width="auto" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Focusable="False" Background="White" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionChanged="ListBoxApplicationsSelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF4EA6EA"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding StateColor}" Width="5" Height="auto" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Rectangle>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,4,0,0">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" FontSize="20" Padding="2" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,4">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CloudName}" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF666666" />
                                        <TextBlock Text=" - " FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF666666" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FF666666" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <Button Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Focusable="False" Tag="{Binding}" Name="ButtonUpload" ToolTip="Upload Application" Click="ButtonUploadClick">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="/Appsecute;component/Images/upload.png"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Focusable="False" Tag="{Binding}" Name="ButtonStart" Click="ButtonStartClick" ToolTip="Start Application" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStopped}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="/Appsecute;component/Images/play.png" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Focusable="False" Tag="{Binding}" Name="ButtonStop" ToolTip="Stop Application" Click="ButtonStopClick" IsEnabled="{Binding IsStarted}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="/Appsecute;component/Images/stop.png"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Focusable="False" Click="ButtonRestartClick" Tag="{Binding}" Name="ButtonRestart" ToolTip="Restart Application">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="/Appsecute;component/Images/restart.png"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <Label Content="SERVICE INSTANCES" Height="auto" Name="LabelServiceInstances" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Padding="2" Margin="0,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ListBox Height="auto" Name="ListBoxServiceInstances" Width="auto" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
        </Grid>
        <Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="LabelStatus" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="auto" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="10" />
    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

And an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is at the first level below *`DataTemplate`*, here:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

By its nature a *`StackPanel`* will align items to the left, so it's not a layout that's well suited to what you want to do.  Instead try using a *Grid* with two columns, giving the left column *`Width=*`* and the right *`Width=Auto`*.

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                    ...
                </StackPanel>
                <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    ...
                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
        <DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<ListBox>
```

Comment: I've made your changes and updated my original post, this time adding the xaml for the whole window in case it's relevant - The buttons are still floating left unfourtunatley.

Comment: @Tyler I remember now... it's because of the default behaviors of the *ListBox* control.  Change your *ListBox* to an *ItemsControl* and it will work the way you wnat.  Of course, then you won't get the normal *ListBox* behaviors, but maybe you're ok with that ....

Comment: I've just tried that but now my <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle> template can no longer style the padding, background, border brush etc. as the items aren't list items any more they're "control presenters" "Cannot find the Style Property 'Padding' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter'"

Comment: @Tyler sorry, looks like I bit off more than I could chew trying to answer this question.  It looks like you'll need to get into some intense WPF business to style this the way you want.

Comment: @Tyler wait!  I take that back.  Try using the *ListBox*, adding to it *HorizontalContentAlignment=Stretch*.  This works for me in my prototype.

Comment: Thank you!! :) This works perfectly!! If you update your answer with it I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again I've spent ages on this!

Answer (score 1):

In your `ItemContainerStyle`, set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch`. I believe it is Left by default, which may be causing the Grid or StackPanel or whatever container you use to collapse.

Comment: I've made your change and updated the xaml in my first post but still have the same problem :(